# Rvest Turn Final String Into Multiple Rows

Tags: html, r, string, gsub, rvest

I've used rvest to scrape the commentary from a soccer match off ESPNFC.co.uk, but I'm struggling to get the final output that I need.

```
library("rvest")
library("xlsx")
espnfc<-html("http://www.espnfc.co.uk/commentary/422421/commentary.html")
  commentary<-espnfc %>%
  html_nodes("#convo-window") %>%
  html_text() 
commentary <- gsub ( "\n", "", commentary)
commentary <- gsub ( "\r", "", commentary)
commentary <- gsub ( "\t", "", commentary)
```

The final output is a huge character string, however I'd like the action from each minute to be a row in a dataframe, for example:

```
"90'Second Half ends, Liverpool 2, Sunderland 2."
"90'Attempt blocked. Adam Johnson (Sunderland) right footed shot from outside the box is blocked. Assisted by Patrick van Aanholt."
"90'Attempt missed. Jordon Ibe (Liverpool) right footed shot from outside the box is close, but misses to the left. Assisted by Mamadou Sakho."
"90'Lucas Leiva (Liverpool) wins a free kick in the attacking half."
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the css selector will make your life easier

```
espnfc<-html("http://www.espnfc.co.uk/commentary/422421/commentary.html")
commentary<-espnfc %>%
html_nodes(".comment p") %>%
html_text() 

minute<-espnfc %>%
html_nodes(".timestamp p") %>%
html_text() 

df<-data.frame(minute=minute,commentary=commentary)
```